# how to catch a parent event in a child component using Angular 9

Tags: angular

So on my parent form I have:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <my-input class="form-component-with-input" [(ngModel)]="request.wallet" name="wallet" #wallet="ngModel" (onValidated)="walletValidated($event)" (onChanged)="walletChanged($event)"></my-input>
</div>

.......
<mainwallet [request]="request"></mainwallet>
```

Where mainwallet is my child component.

Mainwallet has a couple of dropdowns which get populated in the ngOnInit event and this is all fine. In my mainWallet component I have declared a function:

```
 public walletValidated(isValid: boolean) {
 .......
}
```

So when the user triggers the onValidated event on the parent how do I get it to call the event on the child?

Comment: Take a look at https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: @MikeS. If you want to turn this into the answer I will accept this. The Service example gave me exactly the thing I was looking for